# Servlet отправка неоднородных данных

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Как отправить и картинки и разметку? Пихаю в `OutputStream` картинку, выставляю `setContentType("imeg/jpeg")`. Все норм, но таких картинок я хочу отправить не одну! + должна быть какая-никакая разметка. Есть конечно варианты использовать `<img src=""...>` в JSP, но это нужно файл сначала создавать, а это все время. Что делать?

Comment: Что значит фраза "но это нужно файл сначала создавать, а это все время"?

Comment: время на создание файла, типо так я сразу все в аутпутстрим записываю, а так мне придется сначала создавать файл, следовательно время на обработку запроса увеличится

Comment: Никаких файлов создавать не надо. Вы один раз на этапе разработки создаёте jsp-шаблон, он компилируется в сервлет и остаётся только на этапе выполнения передавать ему необходимые данные.

Comment: Я про файл изображения. Т.е. что бы использовать _<img scr="">_ мне придется сначала создать этот файл. А так я сразу из инпута в аутпут записываю

Comment: Можно изображение отдавать из сервлета, а в атрибуте `src` указывать адрес этого сервлета.

Comment: хмм... А вот это уже интересно, спасбо, завтра обязательно попробую

Comment: огромное спасибо, это сработало! С гет запросами теперь все хорошо. Можно маленький вопрос, имеет ли право на жизнь такой подход?

Comment: Такой подход часто используется.